# subtracting 0xB0 from 0xAF caused an overflow 0xFFFFFFFFF

Tags: assembly, overflow

Hexadecimal number `0xAF` is either the signed number `-81` or the unsigned number `175`.
Hexadecimal number `0xB0` is either the signed number `-80` or the unsigned number `176`.

Signed subtraction: `(-81) - (-80) = -1`
unsigned subtraction: `175 - 176 = -1`
`0xB0` two's complement is `0x50`

Thus `0xAF - 0xB0 = 0xAF + 0x50 = 0xFF`
But instead of the expected result `0xFF` we receive an overflow `0xFFFFFFFF`....

Both in Windows Calculator for programmers and in assembly

```
mov al, 0afh
mov bl, 0b0h
sub al, bl
```

What am i missing?

Comment: You can't get a result of `0xFFFFFFFF` since that's 32 bits and you only got 8. You are probably looking at extra bits of `eax`. You should only look at the low 8 bits, aka. `al`, and that's `0xFF` all right. Note that your code does not change the top bits of `eax` so whatever is there at the start is still there at the end, it won't always be `0xFFFFFF??` PS: of course if you do the calculation on 32 bits, you will get `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: it is just a sign extended representation.  the 8 bit register only holds 0xFF as you expect, but whatever you are using to view it appears to be 32 bit and is sign extending.

Answer (score 0):

What is your precision? Are you sure the 2's complement of `0xB0` isn't `0xFFFFFF50` (in case of 32bits precision)?

Remember that the 2's complement representation takes your precision in consideration. The 2's complement of `0xB0` would be `0x50` if you had 8 bits of precision, but as you say the answer was `0xFFFFFFFF`.... you must have a higher precision.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12753585)

Comment: Ok, so if a question is incomplete and I don't have enough reputation I shouldn't anwer it? Or should I assume things and explain every scenario?

Thanks btw

Comment: @MrOrange : If a question is incomplete or too broad and requires clarification then it should be a comment. If you can't comment don't answer, move onto a different question that doesn't require clarification. The reasons for this are discussed in this [Meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/271768)

Answer (score 0):

The debugging in assembly code showed that when the `sub` instruction set was executed (`sub al, bl`) then the carry flag was set, indicating that there is an overflow. That was a bit confusing to me because i was wrongly thinking that there is no actual overflow when we subtract 0xB0 from 0xAF.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, ExitCode:DWORD

.data

.code
main PROC

    pushfd
    xor eax, eax    ;eax = 0
    xor ebx, ebx    ;ebx = 0

    ;execute the subtraction 0xAF - 0xB0
    mov al, 0afh    ;unsigned number 175 or signed number -81
    mov bl, 0b0h    ;unsigned number 176 or signed number -80
    push eax;       ;save eax to stack
    sub al, bl      ;175 < 176 -> CF = 1, carry bit = 1

    ;execute the subtraction  0xB0 - 0xAF
    pop eax;        ;restore eax
    popfd           ;restore flags
    pushfd          ;save flags
    push ebx        ;store ebx to stack
    sub bl, al      ;176 > 175 -> CF = 0, carry bit = 0

    ;execute the addition 0xB0 + 0x51
    pop ebx         ;restore ebx
    popfd           ;restore flags
    pushfd          ;save flags
    add bl, 51h     ;0xB0 - 0xAF = 0xB0 + 0x51 -> CF = 1, carry bit = 1
    popfd           ;restore flags, avoid stack memory corruption

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0    
main ENDP

END main
```

The subtraction 0xB0 - 0xAF = 0x01 has no borrow bit from the left of MSB:

```
0xB0 - 0XAF 
borrow bit  0000 1112
Hex 0xB0    1011 0000
Hex 0xAF    1010 1111
-------------------------------------+
            0000 0001
```

There is no borrowing bit from the left bit after MSB. Thus the carry flag is not set. But the opposite subtraction 0xAF - 0xB0 requires a carry out borrow bit.

```
0XAF – 0xB0 
Borrow bit 5    0002 0000
Borrow bit 7    0120 0000
Carry Borrow    2000 0000
Hex 0xAF        1010 1111
Hex 0xB0        1011 0000
-------------------------------------+
11111111111     1111 1111
```

The unsigned subtraction is 175 - 176 = -1 which is a contradiction because the result can't be a signed number. Thus the hexadecimal result 0xFF, truncated in 8 bits, would be the unsigned number 255 and not -1. The actual binary we got from the above subtraction, was 1111 1111 with infinite preceding bits set which is the infinite hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF... which is the infinite unsigned number. Thus there is an actual unsigned overflow. When we borrow a carry bit from the left of MSB, we have to move infinite positions to the left because there is no available bit set to borrow from.

Comment: *there is a carry bit after MSB on the left*: No idea what you're talking about.  `add` and `sub` don't have a carry-in, and definitely not a conditionally-ignored carry-in.  Use `adc` or `sbb` if you want to use CF as an input.  Perhaps [this carry vs. overflow guide](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) will help.  Carry is set based on unsigned wraparound, not 2's complement signed overflow.  (the Overflow flag is set based on that). See also other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Yes you are right. I mixed things up. I will correct them. But the question still remains, with no good answer. The subtraction 0xAF - 0xB0 = 0xFF causes the carry flag to be set, indicating that there is an unsigned overflow. And indeed a borrow bit is required from the position on the left of MSB and that's why the carry flag is set. But there is no actual unsigned overflow. The hexadecimal number 0xFF can fit into register al. That is what i am talking about, Peter.

Comment: `0xFF` is the infinite-precision result truncated to 8 bits.  The infinite-precision result has an infinite string of leading `1` bits.  (This is what a carry-out from a subtract means).  Of course the low 8 bits of the result fits in 8 bits; that's *always* the case.  And yes it does wrap around.  Decrementing `0xAF` by one `0xB0` times gets you to zero, and then one more decrement causes wraparound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter.